# .msi uninstallation is not removing previous files

Tags: .net, windows-installer, desktop-application

I have visual studio "Setup Project" project which creates .msi

In set up project, we have set Remove Previous Versions to True.

Everytime when we create a new version we do update the Version and ProductCode which install the exe. When you check the installed version in Programme and Features it shows the new version number but it doesnt actually have the latest changes.

But if you manually un-install the existing version and then install, everything works

Is anybody has an idea or solution?

Comment: Is this your own installer or a third party installer? Please elaborate extensively as we can not tell what is what from this description.

Comment: It is not 3rd party installer. I mean when the client install the application with .msi file, files of previous version are not removed properly and because of that updated features can't be seen in new application